# ISODate in MongoDB query with double quotes

Tags: mongodb, double-quotes, isodate

I'm trying to make a MongoDB query, here's how I'm trying to do, part of my query:

```
db.admin_25c6b5.aggregate( 
[ 
{ "$match" :  { "attr" : "temperature", "ts" : {"$gte" : ISODate("2015-01-01"), "$lt" : ISODate("2025-01-01") } } },
{ "$sort" : { "ts" : 1 } }, 
{ "$project" :  { "value" : 1, "_id" : 0 } }
])
```

When I tried this on Robo 3T it worked, but not on Grafana, it gave me the message *Unexpected token I in JSON at position 63*, the ISODate didn't work.

Then, I tried to add quotes:

```
db.admin_25c6b5.aggregate( 
[ 
{ "$match" :  { "attr" : "temperature", "ts" : {"$gte" : "ISODate("2015-01-01")", "$lt" : "ISODate("2025-01-01")" } } },
{ "$sort" : { "ts" : 1 } }, 
{ "$project" :  { "value" : 1, "_id" : 0 } }
])
```

The new error message is: *Unexpected number in JSON at position 73*

I tried using this, but it didn't work:

```
db.admin_25c6b5.aggregate( 
[ 
{ "$match" :  { "attr" : "temperature", "ts" : {"$gte" : "ISODate(\"2015-01-01\")", "$lt" : "ISODate(\"2025-01-01\")" } } },
{ "$sort" : { "ts" : 1 } }, 
{ "$project" :  { "value" : 1, "_id" : 0 } }
])
```

The new error message is *Unexpected end of JSON input*

I think the problem is that I am trying to use double quotes inside double quotes, do you have any idea to solve this?

Comment: please add sample JSON that is complete in key-value pair.

Comment: I think I done what I needed, the full JSON queries are here.